# Unable to receive Firebase push notitication in Maui app via Topic

Tags: c#, firebase-cloud-messaging, maui

I am new to MAUI and am trying to receive push notifications via Firebase in my Android app via Topics.

If I use the device token directly then it works OK, but trying to send via a topic then I don't get any notification at all.  I am using Firebase.Admin nuget package.
Somewhere I have configured something wrong, but I don't know what and where.

This is my maui app where I create the notification channel.

```
 private void CreateNotificationChannel()
 {
        var channelId = $"{PackageName}.Devices";
        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        var channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "Devices", NotificationImportance.Default);
        notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        FirebaseCloudMessagingImplementation.ChannelId = channelId;
        FirebaseMessaging.Instance.SubscribeToTopic("Devices");
 }
```

I have a simple app which sends the notifications (for testing)

```
var message = new Message()
{
    Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"myData", "detail sent in message" },
    },
    //Token = deviceToken,
    Topic = "Devices",
    Notification = new Notification()
    {
        Title = "Test from code",
        Body = "Body of message is here"
    }
};
```

As you see, the Topic matches the channel name in the Maui app.
If I change this to use the `deviceToken` instead, then it works OK.

I don't get any errors, the client app says that the message was sent OK, so I think it must be an error in the Maui app, but I don't know how to fix the problem

Comment: where are you calling [subscribeToTopic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#subscribe_the_client_app_to_a_topic)?

Comment: @Jason I had missed that from my code sample above (now added)!  I am calling it at the end of CreateNotificationChannel()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to find the issue.

The method CreateNotificationChannel() was part of the Android specification application code.

So I moved this line

```
FirebaseMessaging.Instance.SubscribeToTopic("Devices");
```

to a different part of the code (called during application DI is built during application start-up) and then the notification worked also for topics.